# live update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc 3.0 and am writing a feature to update info instantly on a main panel after a user has made an action.

So all other users that are online will see live update from other users.

I'm guessing to use ajax + jquery and web api but not sure how to make "live"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Real live is only possible with something like websockets. But you can simulate 'live' by using ajax calls with small repeating intervalls to check for new data.

Answer (score 0):

Google for techniques such as "long poll", and "web sockets". Essentially, the browser makes a long-lived connection to the server and the server pushes data down that connection when it's available.

Comment: thanks for your advise, now i know what direction to look for

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Socket.io Library if you want to use websockets.

http://socket.io/

> Socket.IO aims to make realtime apps possible in every browser and
>   mobile device, blurring the differences between the different
>   transport mechanisms. It's care-free realtime 100% in JavaScript.

Socket.io degrades gracefully:

> In order to provide realtime connectivity on every browser, Socket.IO
>   selects the most capable transport at runtime, without it affecting
>   the API.

```
WebSocket
Adobe® Flash® Socket
AJAX long polling
AJAX multipart streaming
Forever Iframe
JSONP Polling
```